# Stopping user from deleting the database

Tags: android

In android 2.2, we cannot disable the "Clear data" button in Manage Application, My requirement is like I have to stop user to delete the database. I done lots of googling for this, but i cannot get any proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you should prevent user deleting some vital for your application data by managing the storage right and being able to reload data that can be removed by the user. You can't prevent a user removing your app's data, it's a user's right if he wants to get more free space on his phone. [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) resource should help you manage your data.